# Why isn't my sticky header changing background color and text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in my header. Its purpose is to stay on the page when you scroll. So with a fixed position and being sticky. During scrolling, its background changes color as well as the text. However, it doesn't work. It's sticky and fixed, but nothing else appears. So the background and color don't change. Here's the HTML, CSS and JS.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
  });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");

html, body{
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.6s;
  padding: 40px 5px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

header.sticky {
  padding: 40px 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

header .logo {
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header ul li {
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

li a:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

.section1, .section2, .section3, .section4, .section5, .section6, .section7{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.section1::before{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(moonlight.jpg) top center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.section2 {
  background: #141414;
  color: white;
}

.section3 {
  background: white;
}

.section4 {
  background: white;
}

.section5 {
  background: white;
}

.section6 {
  background: white;
}

.section7 {
  background: white;
}

.About{
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Heavy';
}

.section1 .parallax-hangman {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Heavy';
  font-size: 15vw;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 5px 5px 70px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


#image-track {
    display: flex;
    gap: 4vmin;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%); 
    user-select: none;
  }
  
#image-track > .image {
    width: 40vmin;
    height: 56vmin;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 100% center;
}

#image-track .image {
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

#image-track .image.full-size {
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

@media (width <= 1499px){
    .html{
    flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

````html
```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <title>Hangman</title>
</head>
<body>
<header id = "top">
    <a href="#section1" class="logo">Logo</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#section2">Sommaire</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Go</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section4">Git</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section5">Gitea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section6">Règles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section7">Jeu</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </header>
    <div class="section1" id = "section1">
        <div class="parallax-hangman">HANGMAN</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section2" id="section2">
        <div class="About">Sommaire</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section3" id="section3">
        <div class="About">Go, c'est quoi ?</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section4" id="section4">
        <div class="About">Git, c'est quoi ?</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section5" id="section5">
        <div class="About">Gitea, c'est quoi ?</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section6" id = "section6">
        <div id="image-track" data-mouse-down-at="0" data-prev-percentage = "0">
            <img class="image" src="installation.png" draggable="false"/>
            <img class="image" src="https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/153553034/289691894-ecf6bf92-9fd6-427e-8c83-3ddce18eefa2.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVCODYLSA53PQK4ZA%2F20240113%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240113T121811Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=8f3debc38bb1c093582577e66f2ebf0def75f46aa82cdb1297a3f7cf271a2761&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=730370407" draggable="false"/>
            <img class="image" src="Settings.PNG" draggable="false"/>
            <img class="image" src="https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/153553034/289691782-8643510e-6288-4151-8e0b-018a3d276265.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVCODYLSA53PQK4ZA%2F20240113%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240113T121912Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=a0b8072d79ad6369fe85ce11894b886faf3727fa371dc4d14f0e052ab28d8774&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=730370407" draggable="false"/>
        </div>   
    </div>    
    <div class="section7" id = "section7"> Jeu </div>
    <script src="javaScript.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
````

Comment: Why don't you use (instead of a JS solution) CSS `position: sticky;` ? Also, don't share code that is irrelevant for the question. Just create a demo that encompasses the header, a scrollable BODY, and the minimal CSS. Read [mre].

Comment: I didn't know that one. So I should delete the "header.sticky thing" and add "position sitcky" here =>
header {
  position: fixed;

?

Comment: Basically, remove the `position: fixed;`, remove the JS, and just use `position: sticky;` . Also ,avoid over-styling the `header` tag. Avoid custom styling for tags in general. Use the `#top` selector instead.

Comment: If I put "position: fixed" it works , even without JS. It's kinda perfect, so i don't really need position sticky, the problem is that, idk why it aint getting a background color when i scroll.

Comment: Don't query the DOM in JS for a `"header"` use the ID #top. Also store the element beforehand in a variable.

Comment: Alright, imma try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls add 'true' at your eventListener and also remove from your css in your html and body the height:100% and it will work

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
    let position = window.scrollY
    console.log(position)
    const header = document.getElementById("top");
      header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY>0)
  },true);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");

html, body{
    /* height: 100vh; */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    width: 100vw;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.6s;
  padding: 40px 5px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

header.sticky {
  padding: 40px 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

header .logo {
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header ul li {
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

li a:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

.section1, .section2, .section3, .section4, .section5, .section6, .section7{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.section1::before{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(moonlight.jpg) top center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.section2 {
  background: #141414;
  color: white;
}

.section3 {
  background: white;
}

.section4 {
  background: white;
}

.section5 {
  background: white;
}

.section6 {
  background: white;
}

.section7 {
  background: white;
}

.About{
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Heavy';
}

.section1 .parallax-hangman {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Heavy';
  font-size: 15vw;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 5px 5px 70px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


#image-track {
    display: flex;
    gap: 4vmin;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%); 
    user-select: none;
  }
  
#image-track > .image {
    width: 40vmin;
    height: 56vmin;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 100% center;
}

#image-track .image {
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

#image-track .image.full-size {
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

@media (width <= 1499px){
    .html{
    flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Hangman</title>
</head>
<body>
<header id = "top">
    <a href="#section1" class="logo">Logo</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#section2">Sommaire</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Go</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section4">Git</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section5">Gitea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section6">Règles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section7">Jeu</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </header>
    <div class="section1" id = "section1">
        <div class="parallax-hangman">HANGMAN</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section2" id="section2">
        <div class="About">Sommaire</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section3" id="section3">
        <div class="About">Go, c'est quoi ?</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section4" id="section4">
        <div class="About">Git, c'est quoi ?</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section5" id="section5">
        <div class="About">Gitea, c'est quoi ?</div>
    </div>

    <div class="section6" id = "section6">
        <div id="image-track" data-mouse-down-at="0" data-prev-percentage = "0">
            <img class="image" src="installation.png" draggable="false"/>
            <img class="image" src="https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/153553034/289691894-ecf6bf92-9fd6-427e-8c83-3ddce18eefa2.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVCODYLSA53PQK4ZA%2F20240113%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240113T121811Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=8f3debc38bb1c093582577e66f2ebf0def75f46aa82cdb1297a3f7cf271a2761&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=730370407" draggable="false"/>
            <img class="image" src="Settings.PNG" draggable="false"/>
            <img class="image" src="https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/153553034/289691782-8643510e-6288-4151-8e0b-018a3d276265.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVCODYLSA53PQK4ZA%2F20240113%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240113T121912Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=a0b8072d79ad6369fe85ce11894b886faf3727fa371dc4d14f0e052ab28d8774&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=730370407" draggable="false"/>
        </div>   
    </div>    
    <div class="section7" id = "section7"> Jeu </div>
    <script src="javaScript.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Could you explain me why ?

Comment: because your window needs to be scrolled and if you put it to 100% height seems that it does not  scroll

Comment: Oh, yeah. Alright, thanks for your help. Take care and have a good day.

Comment: you welcome and enjoy coding